# How to inject command into test command

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

I have a self written script like (`./myscript`) and I want to call some commands in that script. So I want to learn how to inject commands into a shell script like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

if test 1 -eq $1; then
        echo "Correct answer."
fi
```

Is it possible to inject another command here? When I try to inject a command like this `./myscript.sh "1 && echo Yes"`, I get this output:

```
+ test 1 -eq 1 '&&' echo Yes
./myscript.sh: line 7: test: too many arguments
```

I tried also several other ways to inject something here, but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: What do you want to achieve: inject some code to be executed **in exactly this script** or write a (buggy) script where you can inject code by using specific input or command line arguments? Please [edit] your question to clarify this, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: @Bodo I changed my question slightly. I hope this clarifies your comment.

Comment: Your script is just about safe enough not to be broken with unexpected input. If you want to break it with external influence then changing either the `PATH` or the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` settings would probably be the way to go